# Cross browser addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, button, event-handling

i have used multiple EventListeners but this particular one is not working in IE:

```
document.querySelector('#assets').addEventListener('loaded', function () {
 document.getElementById('startbutton').style.display = "inline";
});

document.querySelector('#assets').addEventListener('loaded', function () {
 document.getElementById('loadingbutton').style.display = "none";
});
```

I want display a button while assets load and then remove the button with display none as soon as the assets have loaded. Problem is that the loadingbutton does not get removed, so the style does not get applied. This only happens in Internet Explorer. How do i write it with attachEvent so that it works?

The buttons html:

```
<button id="startbutton" class="my_popup_close button" onclick="playSound();setTimeout(showDiv, 2000);" name="answer" value="Show Div" style="display: none;">Ready</button>

<button class="buttonloading loader" id="loadingbutton">Loading<span class="loader__dot">.</span><span class="loader__dot">.</span><span class="loader__dot">.</span></button>
```

Comment: Both events listened to are the same, combine the callback commands, and save yourself a few bytes there.

Comment: Do you have a working code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listened to element is the same, as well as the events. You should combine the callback like:

```
document.querySelector('#assets').addEventListener('loaded', function (){
   // display #startbutton and hide #loadingbutton
   document.getElementById('startbutton').style.display = "inline";
   document.getElementById('loadingbutton').style.display = "none";
});
```